# Python nested context manager on multiple lines

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

In Python 2.6, we used to format our nested context manager that way:

```
with nested(
    context1,
    context2
) as a, b:
    pass
```

From Python 2.7 and on, `nested` is deprecated. I've seen lots of example of multiple context manager on a single line, but I can't find a syntax that allow them on multiple lines. How would you do this?

```
# That's working fine
with context1 as a, context2 as b:
    pass

# But how do we make it multine?
# These are not working
with (
    context1,
    context2
) as a, b:
    pass

with context1 as a,
    context2 as b:
    pass
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been flagged as duplicate. The other post don't answer the question. I agree that Python should propose a parenthese based syntax as for the if statement.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Python 3.10 and newer

Starting from Python 3.10, [parentheses are allowed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers), and you can finally do this:

```
with (
    context1 as a,
    context2 as b
):
    pass
```

#### Backslash characters

> Two or more physical lines may be joined into logical lines using
> backslash characters (`\`)

(citing the *[Explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining)* section)

If you want put context managers on different lines, you can make that work by ending lines with backslashes:

```
with context1 as a,\
     context2 as b:
    pass
```

#### `contextlib.ExitStack`

[`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) is a

> context manager that is designed to make it easy to programmatically
> combine other context managers and cleanup functions, especially those
> that are optional or otherwise driven by input data.

It's available in Python 3.3 and newer, and allows to enter a variable number of context managers easily. For just two context managers the usage looks like this:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as es:
    a = es.enter_context(context1)
    b = es.enter_context(context2)
```

#### Nesting

It's possible to split a context expression across several *nested* `with` statements:

> With more than one item, the context managers are processed as if
> multiple with statements were nested:
>
> ```
> with A() as a, B() as b:
> ```
>
> suite is equivalent to
>
> ```
> with A() as a:
>     with B() as b:
>         suite
> ```

(from [*The with statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement))

Comment: Is this the only syntax - because it's very ugly... :(

Comment: Can't believe I'm saying it but in this instance python syntax is terrible compared to lisp. Multiple assignments in a (let) or other binding form looks completely natural... but this is awkward.

Comment: What if `B()` requires `a`? Is there a way to pass it in?

Answer (score 14):

There is a way to creatively use the parentheses and avoid the backslash: parenthesize the expression before `as`. Not very sightly, though:

```
with (
  open('/etc/passwd')) as foo, (
  open('/tmp/bar')) as bar:
  pass  # this parses correctly
```

It's easy to nest more and more if needed.

Comment: This is the prettiest solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to avoid backslashes in this case though? The open parens play essentially the same role here, but it also becomes more cryptic.

Comment: @isarandi: A backslash as line continuation is easier to break when editing than some other things. PEP-8 recommends the use of parens in favor of backslash continuation. BTW the same PEP-8 suggests to use a ``\`` exactly with multiple `with` statements. I personally prefer nesting of `with`, but added this answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

```
with context1 as a, \
context2 as b:
pass
```

Like any line-break, backslash provides the solution

Answer (score 2):

Your example is equivalent to:

```
with context1 as a:
    with context2 as b:
        pass
```

which looks nice on two lines.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement